# How to Complete path of Invalid or Incomplete Contour in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour, edge-detection

Hello i am using following image to detect the mango shape using python blob detection.

[image: The mango image]

I am using the following code

```
img = cv2.imread(name, -1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(self.base + self.output + '_gray.jpg', gray)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200) 
cv2.imwrite(self.base + self.output + '_edge.jpg', edged)

(_, cnts, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts.sort(key = cv2.contourArea)
```

I manged to find edges and then contours the edge output is following

[image: Mango Edges]

Now here comes the actual problem when i try to draw or crop the largest contour the mango is not croped instead the deceased area is treated as the largest contour according to my understanding it is due to the incomplete path of the largest contour covering the mango edges but then it is treated as invalid due to incomplete path and hence second largest contour is included in the array and the main one is skipped

I just can't find a way to fix the path or complete the contour path

The final cropped output is following which is not desired

[image]

Comment: I am always devastated to see how programmers prefer edge detection over segmentation in such easy cases.

Comment: what do you suggest? how image segmentation can accommodate my solution i am OK with what ever approach but i don't know much about image segmentation could you please give an example code snippet

Comment: Convert to Hue or Saturation and binarize.